# Use 2nd capture group to match another pattern in regex

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with defining a regex that can find the following:

For all PLUXXX,Y=11, I need to use XXX to find the value associated with REFXXX.

Given the input:

```
REF178=1234
OTHER RANDOM DATA LINE
PLU178,1=11
OTHER RANDOM DATA LINE
PLU179,1=11
REF179=5678
OTHER RANDOM DATA LINE
OTHER RANDOM DATA LINE
REF180=5432
PLU180,1=12
REF181=123432
```

I would like to get 1234 and 5678 back. REF180 is ignored since PLU180 equals 12. REF181 is ignored since there is no matching PLU.

The input file has many lines and multiple REF/PLU pairs with different XXX values. The order of REF/PLU lines are random and there are other lines of data in between.

I'm only interested in the REF values if the matching PLU has a value of 11.

I can match the PLU with

```
(PLU)(.+)(\,.+=11)
```

knowing that the 2nd capture group somehow should be paired with REF to find the wanted value.

I imagine that positive lookahead should be used, but can't figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: Maybe something like `(?m)^REF\d+=\K\d+(?=\nPLU.+=11$)`? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ud0B3O/1). Match lines starting with `REF`, one or more digits, then `=`, omit the text matched, grab one or more digits, and then check if the next line starts with `PLU` and ends with `=11`.

Comment: Not quite - the order of REF/PLU is not guaranteed and there can be other lines of data in between. So it is important to only find REF if there is a matching PLU with the same postfix number. I will update my question with this info.

Comment: You tagged your question with regex only, but some logic around the regex may be necessary or more practical. Do you need this to work within a specific programming language or command shell?

Comment: I'm pretty open about which environment to use. I'm currently using Notepad++ to search many files for this pattern, but could also be doing this in Bash or similar.

Comment: Currently it is just for identifying which files that contains this pattern, but would be nice to extract the REF= numbers for further processing.

Comment: I have updated the question. Order of REF/PLU lines are random and there can be other lines of data in between to be ignored.

Comment: Ok, does `^REF(\d+)=\K\d+(?=(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RPLU\1,1=11$)` work for you? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ud0B3O/3).  If it does, this can be further tweaked in Notepad++.

Comment: Yes, that looks very promising. It does not account for the cases with PLU comes before REF, but that should be rare cases. Also, if I add more lines I get a catastrophic backtracking error, but that might be the demo tool?

Comment: You got CA because the `s` flag was mistakenly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^REF(\d+)=\K\d+(?=(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RPLU\1,1=11$)|^PLU(\d+),1=11(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RREF\2=\K\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ud0B3O/5) (the `m` flag is on automatically in Notepad++). Note that the *`.` matches newline* must be disabled.

*Details*:

- `^REF(\d+)=\K\d+(?=(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RPLU\1,1=11$)` - Cases where `REF` is before `PLU`:

  - `^REF` - `REF` at the start of  a line
  - `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
  - `=` - a `=` char
  - `\K` - removes all text matched so far
  - `\d+` - one or more digits (consumed text)
  - `(?=(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RPLU\1,1=11$)` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there are zero or more (but as few as possible) lines not starting with `REF` + digit and then a line having `PLU`, same value as in Group 1, `,1=11` and the end of the line immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `^PLU(\d+),1=11(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RREF\2=\K\d+` - Cases where `PLU` is before `REF`. Analogous to the first part, but `PLU` and `REF` are swapped.

See the Notepad++ demo:

[image]

Comment: @RasmusNielsen And if you want to extract them in Notepad++, you can use `(?:^REF(\d+)=(\d+)(?=(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RPLU\1,1=11$)|^PLU(\d+),1=11(?:\R(?!REF\d).*)*?\RREF\3=(\d+))|(?s).` and replace with `(?1$2\n:?3$4\n)`.

Comment: @RasmusNielsen Also, if you are interested in what I have done here, please check out this ["*Extracting multiple matches in a Notepad++ document*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWXm-yZUoK0) YT video of mine.

Comment: Thank you very much - I will give it a look :)